# Difference between pointwise and uniform confidence sets

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

According to Wasserman's [All of Nonparametric Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000VI6X5W) p.6, let $\mathfrak{F}$ be a set of distribution functions $F$ and $\theta$ some quantity of interest. A *uniform asymptotic confidence set* $C_n$ is defined as
$$
  \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}\inf_{F\in\mathfrak{F}}\mathbb{P}_F(\theta \in C_n) \geq 1 - \alpha
$$

and a pointwise asymptotic confidence set defined as
$$
  \textrm{for every } F\in \mathfrak{F},\;\; \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}_F(\theta \in C_n) \geq 1 - \alpha
$$

What is the difference between *pointwise* and *uniform* asymptotic confidence sets? Can you give examples of the two and why it is sometimes not possible to prove existence of a uniform set but possible to prove a pointwise set?

Comment: The sets may be the same.

Comment: Basically, uniform asymtotic confidence sets are those procedures for identifying confidence sets for which coverage converges to asymptotic size independent of which part of the parameter space the true parameter is in ($F$). So for pointwise confidence sets, whilst asymptotically coverage is guaranteed, it might occur at a really slow rate for some underlying true parameters, and much faster for others.

Comment: Btw, uniform confidence sets guarantee pointwise coverage.

Comment: Hmmm, im not sure i understand fully what you mean. Could you say that a the convergence for pointwise sets depend on the underlying parameters but uniform does not? Why do uniform guarantee pointwise then? Are they different in some way or is it just because for uniform convergence is constant in the parameters which would make uniform a special case of pointwise?

Comment: @while You want to find an interval that locates the true underlying parameter with a high probability. Wouldn't be terrible if your procedure worked really well (in terms of needing 10 data points to get there) if the true parameter value was 2, and worked really poorly (needing 1000 data points) when the parameter value was 3? Uniform procedures are those that work equally well (or badly) for each (unknown) value of the true parameter. You should be able to convince yourself that uniform coverage implies pointwise coverage.

Comment: Is this a correct interpretation: If F is not a closed set, and there is some limit point that is not in F, then it could happen that for that point, $\lim_n \inf P_F(\theta\in C) < 1-\alpha$, and in this case we may have pointwise asymptotic confidence but not uniform asymptotic confidence?

Answer (score 0):

You can see many similar examples in real analysis.

Let's say the $F$ can be indexed as $F_i$(The $\mathfrak{F}$ is countable). The confidence set $C_n$ have those property:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P_{F_i}(\theta \in C_n) & \ge 1-\alpha \quad if \quad i \le n\\
& < 1-\alpha \quad otherwise
\end{aligned}
$$

So $C_n$ is pointwise asymptotic $1-\alpha$ confidence set, but not uniform asymptotic $1-\alpha$ confidence set.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an asymptotic 95% confidence interval for the mean of a univariate continuous random variable, based on the central limit theorem:
$$[\bar X - 1.96 S/\sqrt{n},\; \bar X+1.96 S/\sqrt{n}]$$

Let ${\cal F}$ be the set of distributions with finite means and variances.  For any distribution having finite mean and variance, the confidence interval has coverage converging to 95%, by the central limit theorem. Given a large enough sample size, the confidence interval coverage will be as close to 95% as you want.

However, the sample size you need for a specified confidence interval accuracy does depend on the distribution. More specifically, it's sensitive to the skewness and kurtosis of the distribution (and probably to higher moments).  Distributions with higher standardised skewness and excess kurtosis need large sample sizes for the central limit theorem to give a good approximation to the distribution of the mean.

If you want, say, coverage between 94.9% and 95.1%, then for any distribution $F$ you can specify a sample size $N_F$ that is big enough for **that** distribution. But you can't specify a **single** $N$ that works for all distributions, because the standardised skewness and excess kurtosis can be arbitrarily high. No matter what $N$ you pick, I can find a distribution that's bad enough to need a larger $N$.